# Save picture/video to Windows 7 file

Tags: camera, file-sharing

Hi I use raspberry pi from my Windows 7 PC via SSH (putty). What is the easiest way to save file from Raspberry pi to Windows. For example I have program which take photo and  I want to this photo will be automatically saved to Windows 7 file. Should I create shared file and set path in program or what is the easiest way?

Comment: If both RPi and Windows computer are on the same network, you can probably make use of `samba server` to save / load files over network.

Answer (score 2):

Create a folder in `/media` or `/mnt` called `windows7`. Make sure your raspberry Pi and Windows 7 can talk to each other. In this scenario lets pretend Windows 7 has the IP address `192.168.0.1` while our Raspberry Pi has the address `192.168.0.2`. use `ping` to make sure both machines can reach one another.

1. Share a folder in Windows 7, perhaps `C:\User\MyName\Videos`.

   - Right Click the folder to share
   - Go to properties
   - Hit the share button.
2. On Raspberry Pi you need to do the following:

   - `sudo apt-get install cifs-utils`
   - Now assuming you are going to use `/mnt/windows7`. Type `sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.1/Videos/ /mnt/windows7 -o rw,user='windows7UserName',pass='windows7Password'`*
3. Now you can write any files you want to `/mnt/windows7` and they will show up in your Videos folder on windows. If you have trouble writing to the directory is probably because you are not root. correcting the permissions might fix it or run the program taking the pictures as root.

Comment: I have problem I dont have pass on Windows so i did pass='' and it made input/output error